# cocos2d-x v3 sprite animation issue

Tags: animation, cocos2d-x

I have a little **cocos2d-x v3** Windows project and I want an animated sprite. The sprite I have in an object named Worker with other parameters. To run the animation I tried the following, but it always gives a segmentation fault:

```
//worker.cpp:

...

    void Worker::initAnimationWalk() {
        spritebatch = cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode::create("robo.png");
        auto cache = cocos2d::SpriteFrameCache::getInstance();
        cache->addSpriteFramesWithFile("robo.plist");
        worker = cocos2d::Sprite::createWithSpriteFrameName("robot1.png");
        //spritebatch->addChild(worker);

        Vector<SpriteFrame *> animFrames(3);

        char str[100] = {0};

        for(int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) 
        {
            sprintf(str, "robot%i.png", i);
            cocos2d::SpriteFrame* frame = cache->getSpriteFrameByName( str );
            animFrames.pushBack(frame);
        }

        animation = cocos2d::Animation::createWithSpriteFrames(animFrames, 0.2f);
    }

cocos2d::Animation *Worker::getAnimationWalk() {
    return animation;
}

...

//Worker.h

    #ifndef __WORKER_H__
    #define __WORKER_H__

    #include "cocos2d.h"
    class Worker
    {
    public:
        ...
        void initAnimationWalk();
        cocos2d::Animation *getAnimationWalk();
    private:
        cocos2d::Animation *animation;
        cocos2d::Sprite *worker;
        cocos2d::SpriteBatchNode *spritebatch;
    };

    #endif

//Now i want the animation in my scene: 
//HellowWorldScene.cpp

    void HelloWorld::setMyAction() { //all Worker Objects in an vector
        vector<Worker>::iterator it = workerVector.begin();
        for(int i = 0; i<workerVector.size();i++) {
        it->getWorker()->stopAllActions();
                                auto actionAnim = Animate::create(it->getAnimationWalk());
                                if(it->getWorker()->getPosition().x > 0.50*2*p.x) {
                                    auto action = cocos2d::MoveTo::create(it->getSpeed(),Point(0,it->getWorker()->getPosition().y));
                                    auto sp = Spawn::createWithTwoActions(action, actionAnim);
                                    it->getWorker()->runAction(sp);
                                    it->getWorker()->setFlipX(true);
                                } else {
                                    auto action = cocos2d::MoveTo::create(it->getSpeed(),Point(2*p.x,it->getWorker()->getPosition().y));
                                    auto sp = Spawn::createWithTwoActions(action, actionAnim);
                                    it->getWorker()->runAction(sp);
                                    it->getWorker()->setFlipX(false);
                                }
    }
    it++
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: You should use debugger.

Comment: I found the problem, but cant solve it. Immendiately when my update() function starts, the animation in my Worker objects isn't the same anymore, it has random values. Is it at all possible to have the animations saved in my worker object and use them in my main scene class? With my sprites it works fine, i can use them all in my main scene class, but the animations vanish.

Comment: There is not enough info you provide. Probably you could made a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for your usecase. It's just a guess, but maybe you forget to call `initAnimationWalk()` before `getAnimationWalk()`, so you get uninitialized pointers. Or maybe you are not providing this piece of code. You could code more like in C++ style, than in cocos2d obj-C style, and move all the `initAnimationWalk()` stuff to `Worker` constructor, so it will be called automagically on `vector` creation.

Answer (score 1):

SpriteAnimation auto change images using Animation.

```
Animation *animation2=Animation::create();
    animation2->setDelayPerUnit(0.7f);//Time Duration change Images 
    animation2->addSpriteFrameWithFile("img_1.png");
    animation2->addSpriteFrameWithFile("img_2.png");
    animation2->addSpriteFrameWithFile("img_3.png");

    AnimationCache::getInstance()->addAnimation(animation2, "animation2");
```

SpriteName->runAction(Sequence::create(Animate::create(animation2),NULL));//this animation Only One time

```
          OR
    SpriteName->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Sequence::create(Animate::create(animation2),NULL)));//If Repeate this animation write it..
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SpriteAnimation auto change images using Animation.

Animation *anim=Animation::create();
    anim->setDelayPerUnit(0.7f);//Time Duration change Images 
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("img_01.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("img_02.png");
    anim->addSpriteFrameWithFile("img_03.png");

    AnimationCache::getInstance()->addAnimation(anim, "anim");

SpriteNM->runAction(Sequence::create(Animate::create(anim),NULL));//this animation Only One time

          OR
    SpriteNM->runAction(RepeatForever::create(Sequence::create(Animate::create(anim),NULL)));//If Repeate this animation write it..
```